# dynamic type in generic using from function parameter

Tags: typescript

Sample code

```
interface E<T extends string> {
  operation: T
}

const opt = <T extends string>(op: T) => {
  const res: E<op> = someFunc(op)
}

function someFunc<T extends string>(op: T): E<T> {
  return {
    operation: op
  }
}
```

Here I am passing `op` in my `opt` function and then calling `someFunc`.

> Error: **`'op' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof op'?ts(2749)`**

My Question is:

> **`Is it possible to pass a type of generic function as a parameter variable and use?`**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using generic type parameter as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525618/using-generic-type-parameter-as-parameter)

Comment: Thanks @MikeS. but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question ️ however thanks again ️

Comment: Well, it does.. passing a type as a variable is impossible because they only exist at compile time, but not at runtime.